# Where is stored standalone option when creating app

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

Creating an app with `npx create-nx-workspace` at some point asks if you want to use the standalone component

```
Would you like to use Standalone Components in your application? · Yes
```

Refering to: **monorepo (integrated) setup**.

Where is stored/saved this setting?

I created 2 identical workspaces except for this setting and there is no difference.

Answer (score 2):

This option isn't stored, the prompt refers only to the project creation where the `main.ts` uses `bootstrapApplication()`.

If you want to create new component you will still have to pass the `--standalone` fla.

```
nx g @nx/angular:component my-component --standalone
```